# PostgreSQL - Create and store JSON?

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I am making this discord bot, with this discord bot you will be able to bind up roles to Roblox roles.

In other words, I need to create a dictionary full of IDs and more. What's the best way to do this with PostgreSQL python? I am thinking about creating a JSON file containing a dictionary for each server, but I don't know how to do this. Help?

Comment: If I understood ur question correctly, you need a column of type `jsonb` in ur table

Comment: and simple add a second table for the servers, joining by server id for example.